# Getting existing Embedded Documents from Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to cache friends from social media in the user's doc and am having issues storing/getting them back. 
First, I blindly strip the their friends cache and would just fill it with my fresh fetch of the data, but through that I found out that the embedded Documents must be unique among all the users (I have a couple of friends that are the same in my test accounts and I get:

```
{"name":"MongoError","err":"E11000 duplicate key error index: test-dev.users.$friends.outsideID_1  dup key: { : \"1205314313242\" }","code":11001,"n":0,"connectionId":274,"ok":1}
```

so from this I know that because that embedded document exists in my other already registered and updated account it can't create that document (outsideID is index because I plan on searching using it later))
So then I started trying to OutsideFriend.find({'outsideID':{$in:friendsIDs}}(where friendsIDs is an array of the ids I got from the SM query), etc.. and then in the callback I go through and try added the new friends and just add the existing docs to the user in question so that it's not trying to duplicate it in the system. However, for whatever reason OutsideFrind.find() never returns any docs... which makes me think that the embedded docs aren't centralized... but then why would the first attempt fail?

How am I supposed to do this? (schema below, please let me know if you need any other info!)

current schema:

```
//External friend model                                                                                                                                                                                              
var OutsideFriend = new Schema({
         outsideID:{type:String, index:true, unique:true}
        ,username:String
        ,location:String
        ,avatarURL:String
});

//User model                                                                                                                                                                                                         
var User = new Schema({
        avatarURL:String
       ,mySMID:String
    //Social Media info                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        ,smID:{type:String, index:true, unique:true}
        ,tok:String
        ,tokSec:String
        ,friends:[OutsideFriend]
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot going on in your question, but if you want to query `OutsideFriend` independent of `User`, then you shouldn't be embedding them in the `User` model.  Instead, just store `ObjectId` references to the friends and then [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) that in `User` when you need the full details.  Don't prematurely optimize with embedded copies unless you find you need to as that introduces consistency challenges.

So your `User` model would change to:

```
var User = new Schema({
    avatarURL:String
    //Social Media info
    ,smID:{type:String, index:true, unique:true}
    ,tok:String
    ,tokSec:String
    ,friends:[{type: ObjectId, ref: 'OutsideFriend'}]
};
```

Comment: Well, originally the idea was caching the SM friends' list in the user doc and thus the idea was to have a unique to that user list of users and I assumed that they were completely separate so if userA and userB were both friend with Bob there would be no issue, but appearently I was wrong since I got the above error from that. So how are you suppose to do that? I can just move it out to a ref and populate which was the backup plan(and may for the sake of time), but I would really like to know the "recommended" method of doing this!^^

Comment: @MatthewClark When you embed another schema in an array field (as with `friends`), any indexes defined in that schema are then also created in the embedding (parent) schema's collection.  A unique index in this context means no two `User` docs can contain an `OutsideFriend` with the same name in their `friends` array.  So embedding a schema that contains a unique index is rarely what you want.  I'd suggest creating a separate schema for `friends` without the unique index that only contains the fields you need cached if you still want to use an embedded approach.

Comment: don't you think an embedded approach would be the most performant method? I'm going to be searching over this cache to show the user which of their SM friends are on this system.

Comment: @MatthewClark Don't prematurely optimize.  Lookups by ObjectId are blazingly fast so  often it isn't needed.  It's usually best to keep it simple until you've found it doesn't give you the performance you're looking for.

Comment: fair enough! Thanks for the response I'm going to test it real fast and then most likely give you credit^^